# Checkbox input triggering Bootstrap accordion collapse event

Tags: javascript, svelte, bootstrap-5

Hello guys I'm using Bootstrap 5 accordion, the only problem I have is that the input checkbox is triggering the "collapse" event from the accordion, I tried to move the checkbox outside the range of the button from the accordion but that will look horrible.

I'm using Svelte, rendering each accordion with Each block with Data from the backend!

This is my code right now:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-10 col-sm-10 responsiveFix">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionObjective">
                    {#each objectives as objective}
                        <div class="accordion-item">
                            <h2
                                class="accordion-header"
                                id={"heading" + objective.objectiveId}
                            >
                                <button
                                    class="accordion-button objectiveTitle collapsed"
                                    type="button"
                                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-bs-target={"#collapse" +
                                        objective.objectiveId}
                                    aria-expanded="false"
                                    aria-controls={"collapse" +
                                        objective.objectiveId}
                                >
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input
                                            class="form-check-input"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            
                                            value={objective.objectiveId}
                                            id="myCollapse"
                                            checked={objective.value}
                                            on:click={postObjective(
                                                objective.objectiveId,
                                                objective.value
                                            )}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <span> {objective.title}</span>
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                            <div
                                id={"collapse" + objective.objectiveId}
                                class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                                aria-labelledby={"heading" +
                                    objective.objectiveId}
                                data-bs-parent="#accordionObjective"
                            >
                                <div class="accordion-body">
                                    <span>{objective.description}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {/each}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The output of this code its[image: Checkbox untriggered]

and this is the picture showing my problem after clicking on any checkbox:

[image: checkbox triggered]

I also tried to bind a bootstrap 5 function to the checkbox input but it didn't work

What can I do? Can you throw me any clue? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can remove the event listener from the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Bootstrap 5 as such, but a quick glance at your code shows this: `<button on:click={postObjective(objective.objectiveId, objective.value )}>`

This function is executed at *render time* and the return value added as the event listener for your `on:click`

The correct syntax would be `<button on:click={() => postObjective(....)}>`

As the code is now it probably does not do what you expect.

Edit:

In your case the input is also inside a button, clicking the input will therefore also click the button. To stop this from happening you have to prevent the event from bubbling up, Svelte has a handy helper for that: `<button on:click|stopPropagation={() => postObjective(....)}>`

Comment: Hmmm... that did´nt work but i think its because the ``` on:click ``` its inside an input inside an button. It works well when i put my input outside the button but breaks the accordion.

Comment: that would be because when you click the input you also click the input, you have to stop it from bubbling up: `on:click|stopPropagation={() => ....}`

Comment: Awesome, that did the work! Im gonna check more about stopPropagation(). Thank you very much